Angular 16 double scroll bar issue
In this view are 2 scrollbars showing at once, one for the full page, and another one for the current view if it doesnt fit in 1 screen, which is ridiculous.
Header's sidenav HTML:
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container" autosize hasBackdrop>
    <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" position="end">
        <span *ngIf="!userAuthenticated">Actualmente no estás autenticado</span>
        <span *ngIf="userAuthenticated">Autenticado como {{username}}</span>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/register" *ngIf="!userAuthenticated">
            <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
            <span>Registrarse</span>
        </button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/login" *ngIf="!userAuthenticated">
            <mat-icon>login</mat-icon>
            <span>Iniciar Sesión</span>
        </button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-button (click)="navLogout()" *ngIf="userAuthenticated">
            <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
            <span>Cerrar Sesión</span>
        </button>
    </mat-drawer>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</mat-drawer-container>

app.component.HTML:
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="router-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>

app.component.SCSS:
.router-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

All I know is that the <router-outlet></router-outlet> element in the header component's sidenav is causing all the trouble, if I remove it everything works fine again. Please help.

 is the component that is used to wrap whatever component is loaded/active based on the current URL by the angular router, multiple scrollbars are an issue caused by containers CSS settings rather than anything to do with angular or components... you'll need to investigate and or/share a recreation of the problem with regard to the CSS you're looking at on the elements.
